# Embed a Executable Binary in a shell script

Tags: java, c, shell, binary

First, I already googled but only found examples where a compressed file (say a `.tar.gz`) is embedded into a shell script.

Basically if I have a C program (`hello.c`) that prints a string, say **Hello World!**.

I compile it to get an executable binary

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

Now I have a shell script `testEmbed.sh`

What I am asking is if it is possible to embed the binary (**hello**) inside the shell script so that when I run

```
./testEmbed.sh
```

it executes the binary to print **Hello World!**.

**Clarification**:
One alternative is that I compress the executable into an archive and then extract it when the script runs. What I am asking is if it is possible to run the program without that.

Up until now, I was trying the method [here](http://www.45rpmsoftware.com/45rpmdump/?p=137). But it does not work for me. I guess the author was using some other distribution on another architecture. So, basically this did not work for me. :P

Also, if the workflow for a C program differs from a Java `jar`, I would like to know that too!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. It's actually quite similar in concept to your linked article. The trick is to use `uuencode` to encode the binary into text format then tack it on to the end of your script.

Your script is then written in such a way that it runs `uudecode` on itself to create a binary file, change the permissions then execute it.

`uuencode` and `uudecode` were originally created for shifting binary content around on the precursor to the internet, which didn't handles binary information that well. The conversion into text means that it can be shipped as a shell script as well. If, for some reason your distribution complains when you try to run `uuencode`, it probably means you have to install it. For example, on Debian Squeeze:

```
sudo aptitude install sharutils
```

will get the relevant executables for you. Here's the process I went through. First create and compile your C program `hello.c`:

```
pax> cat hello.c

#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    printf ("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}

pax> gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Then create a shell script `testEmbed.sh`, which will decode itself:

```
pax> cat testEmbed.sh

#!/bin/bash
rm -f hello
uudecode $0
./hello
rm -f hello
exit
```

The first `rm` statement demonstrates that the `hello` executable is being created anew by this script, not left hanging around from your compilation. Since you need the payload in the file as well, attach the encoded executable to the end of it:

```
pax> uuencode hello hello >>testEmbed.sh
```

Afterwards, when you execute the script `testEmbed.sh`, it extracts the executable and runs it.

The reason this works is because `uudecode` looks for certain marker lines in its input (`begin` and `end`) which are put there by `uuencode`, so it only tries to decode the encoded program, not the entire script:

`````````````
pax> cat testEmbed.sh

#!/bin/bash
rm -f hello
uudecode $0
./hello
rm -f hello
exit

begin 755 hello
M?T5,1@$!`0````````````(``P`!````$(,$"#0```#`!@```````#0`(``'
M`"@`'@`;``8````T````-(`$"#2`!`C@````X`````4````$`````P```!0!
: : :
M:&%N9&QE`%]?1%1/4E]%3D1?7P!?7VQI8F-?8W-U7VEN:70`7U]B<W-?<W1A
M<G0`7V5N9`!P=71S0$!'3$E"0U\R+C``7V5D871A`%]?:38X-BYG971?<&-?
4=&AU;FLN8G@`;6%I;@!?:6YI=```
`
end
`````````````

There are other things you should probably worry about, such as the possibility that your program may require shared libraries that don't exist on the target system, but the process above is basically what you need.

---

The process for a JAR file is very similar, except that the way you run it is different. It's still a single file but you need to replace the line:

```
./hello
```

with something capable of running JAR files, such as:

```
java -jar hello.jar
```

Comment: It might also be a good idea to add a `trap 'rm -f hello' SIGINT` to the shell script so that the temporary file gets cleaned up in case the user Ctrl-C's the program.

Comment: Yes, I don't doubt there are a large number of improvements you could make to that code and that _is_ a good one. I don't want to complicate it too much since I'm only trying to get across the concept.

Comment: Above works great when script content is moved around as a file (cp, ftp etc.) but generally does not work if content is cut-and-pasted between machines.  The default encoding for uuencode has characters / sequences that your shell could try to interpret.  For example, in bash this line in uuencode output: M9"TE2"TE32TE4RDN='AT"E!33TQ$/20H96-H;R`D4%,Q*0I04S$](EM<=2`O (note the backtick single quote) produces this error: "-bash: command substitution: line 1: `D4%,Q*0I04S$](EM<=2'".  To make your script cut-and-pastable, use base64 encoding by adding -m option to the uuencode command line.

Comment: Chris, at no stage should you be in a position where the shell is trying to interpret the `uuencode` output. It's meant to be put directly into a file, *after* an `exit` to ensure the shell ignores it totally. If you're cut'n'pasting it into an interactive shell rather than an editor, you're doing it wrong :-)

Comment: This still requires writing a temporary file, so it is not really embedded. I would be interested in a more `eval`ish kind of solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) is what you're describing.

Comment: makeself is an amazing tool, thanks for this info!

Answer (score 3):

The portable way to do this is with the `printf` command and octal escapes:

```
printf '\001\002\003'
```

to print bytes 1, 2, and 3. Since you probably don't want to write that all by hand, the `od -b` command can be used to generate an octal dump of the file, then you can use a `sed` script to strip off the junk and put the right backslashes in place.

Comment: The command to create the string with the octals is `od -b BINARYFILE  | sed -n 's%[0-9]\{4,\}\ \([0-9]\{3\}.*\)%\1%p' | perl -pe 's%^%\\%;s%\ %\\%g;s%\n%%')`. This created octal string is the one, that `printf` has to have as argument.