# Bash script containing binary executable

Tags: bash, unix, binary, dump

Is it possible to write a bash script, which would contain a binary executable program inside?

I mean a script, which would contain a dump of an executable in a textual form, which will be dumped back to an executable by this script when it is executed?

I would love to know a solution, which will work out of the box without a need of installing additional packages. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I know it's possible, because I've seen it done in Intel's MKL installer script.  I'm not sure *how* it was done, but it is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed a Executable Binary in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491704/embed-a-executable-binary-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: java 6 jdk's used to have a form of distribution of a single 80+ MB `.sh` file, where the script "ended" with an `exit 0` line and the binary parts followed it. the script extracted the binary parts from itself with a line like `tail ${tail_args} +189 "$0" > $outname`; did a `trap` with `rm`, did a `sum` for checksum, a `chmod` and executed it like `./$outname`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i never done something like this before ;)
this will compile some c source, create a `b.bash` script containing the binary (and the original script for simple development)

(a.bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$0" == "b.bash" ];then
  tail -n +$[ `grep -n '^BINARY' $0|cut -d ':' -f 1` + 1 ] $0 | base64 -d > a2.out
  chmod +x a2.out
  ./a2.out
  echo $?
  exit
fi

cat "$0" > b.bash
echo "BINARY" >> b.bash
cat > a.c << EOF
int     main(){
        return 12;
}
EOF
gcc a.c 
base64 a.out >> b.bash
```

invoke with (a.bash generates b.bash):

```
bash a.bash ;bash b.bash
```

i don't know how to evade writing out the binary into a temporary file before execution...

Comment: It is a very good answer - the `base64` is the best solution we can use, since it is default installed on all platforms and it is more compact than `xxd` hex.

Comment: I needed to add "-w 0" to base64. Otherwise I had linewrapping which will produce error on decoding. May also help if piped to tr.
`base64 -w 0 a.out >> b.bash`
(or
`base64 a.out | tr >> b.bash`
i don't tried that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410785/bash-script-containing-binary-executable )

Answer (score 10):

Don't reinvent the wheel like several other answers are suggesting, just use the venerable [shar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) command which is precisely doing this by design.

Assuming the file you want to embed in your script is `binaryfile`, simply run

```
$ shar binaryfile > binaryfile.shar
```

and you are set. You have a shell script named `binaryfile.shar` which when executed will extract `binaryfile`.

Comment: But you need `sharutils` package installed, which isn’t default. `base64` is always available, as it is part of the GNU coreutils.

Comment: @erik You assume the OP is using Gnu/Linux but this is not stated. `base64` is no more POSIX than `shar` so isn't either guaranteed to be available on a Unix platform.

Comment: this would seem like the ideal solution except it requires uudecode for binary data, which is not always available. be nice to use `printf` or `echo -e` strings to be extractable with just busybox.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this out and it works.  Hex was generated with xxd.

```
#!/bin/bash

xxd -r >foo <<'EndHere'
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 e003 4000 0000 0000  ..>.......@.....
0000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 000a 0000 0000 0000  @...............
0000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0800 4000 1e00 1b00  ....@.8...@.....
0000040: 0600 0000 0500 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
0000050: 4000 4000 0000 0000 4000 4000 0000 0000  @.@.....@.@.....
...
0001960: 6400 5f65 6461 7461 006d 6169 6e00 5f69  d._edata.main._i
0001970: 6e69 7400                                nit.
EndHere
chmod +x foo
./foo
```

Comment: +1. `base64` is more suited than `xxd` though. It's way more compact.

Comment: Yes, but if you have a hex dump xxd is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a installer script to deploy it on a machine that did not even have tar, and I ended embedding busybox (for tar and gunzip) and the tarball to deploy on a shell script. I did it *the dd way*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_length()
{
    ls -l "$1" | cut -f5 -d' '
}

# First parameter is the number of semicolons to add to second parameter
# NOTE: we do not use an "add_blanks" function directly because it seems bash
# removes duplicated blanks. The workaround is adding other character and
# replacing later using e.g. sed.
add_semicolons()
{
    scratch="$2"
    for n in $(seq 1 $1)
    do
        scratch+=";"
    done
    echo $scratch
}

# Default values
output="installer"
input="deployable.tar.gz"
shell="busybox"

shell_len=$(get_length "$shell")
payload_len=$(get_length "$input")

# START OF INSTALLATION SCRIPT GENERATION.
#
# Note: generated scripts reserves 9 digits for the skip (ibs) offsets.
# When the script is first written, these digits are written as semicolons.
# Later when the lengths are computed, these semicolons are replaced by the
# correct numbers, but the 9-digit length must be preserved by adding blanks
# until 9 digits are filled. Failure to do this will cause the script length
# to vary and offsets would need to be iteratively computed.

# Add shebang
echo "#!/usr/bin/env ash" > "$output"

echo "echo Extracting installer..." >> "$output"
# Add lines to extract binary data and extract payload
echo "mkdir -p /tmp/installer" >> "$output"
echo "dd if=\"$(basename $output)\" ibs=;;;;;;;;; skip=1 | dd ibs=$shell_len count=1 of=/tmp/installer/shell 2>/dev/null" >> "$output"
echo "chmod +x /tmp/installer/shell" >> "$output";
echo "dd if=\"$(basename $output)\" ibs=;;;;;;;;; skip=1 2>/dev/null of=/tmp/installer/payload.tar.gz 2>/dev/null" >> "$output"
# From here on, the binary extraction is completed, do something with extracted files...
# [...]
# Use exit command to avoid the shell script parsing to reach the binary part
echo "echo Done!" >> "$output"
echo "exit 0" >> "$output"

# We reserved 9 blanks for the ibs offsets. Thus fill offsets with blanks up to 9 chars total
script_len=$(get_length "$output")
skip_len=$((script_len + shell_len))

to_add=$((9 - ${#script_len}))
script_len_str=$(add_semicolons $to_add $script_len)
to_add=$((9 - ${#skip_len}))
skip_len_str=$(add_semicolons $to_add $skip_len)

# Add skip values
sed -i "4s/ibs=;;;;;;;;;/ibs=$script_len_str/" "$output"
sed -i "4s/;/ /g" "$output"
sed -i "6s/ibs=;;;;;;;;;/ibs=$skip_len_str/" "$output"
sed -i "6s/;/ /g" "$output"

cat "$shell" >> "$output"
cat "$input" >> "$output"
chmod +x "$output"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your binary to text, and then back to binary using uuencode/uudecode.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuencode

So you can store your binary data as text in your script and output it to a binary file.

uuencode binaryFile > output.txt

And then put that data into your script and when creating the binary file use uudecode.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I got it right you want to include a binary in your script and execute it on script exit?

Here is a `binarymaker` script(This does not only create a script that extracts a binary, but merges any your script with any binary):

```
#!/bin/bash

lineCount=$(wc -l "$1" | cut -f 1 -d ' ') # just get the line count
((lineCount+=2)) # because we are going to append a line

head -n 1 "$1" > "$3" # this is done to ensure that shebang is preserved
echo "trap 'tail -n +$lineCount \$0 > binary; chmod +x binary; ./binary' EXIT" >> "$3"
tail -n +2 "$1" >> "$3"
cat "$2" >> "$3"

exit 0
```

You should run it like this

```
./binarymaker myscript mybinary resultscript
```

If you run `resultscript` then both `myscript` and `mybinary` are going to be executed. You can optionally add a command to `rm` the binary afterwards.

Also, do not forget to **exit** at the end of your script because otherwise it will continue and try to parse binary data.

If you're working with another script and not a binary, then it can be executed from pipe like this:

```
tail -n +$lineCount \$0 | source /dev/stdin
```

But it is not going to work on real binaries. Also, it doesn't work if your bash version is under 4

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line approach using `hexdump` that produces an ascii shell script that will output a binary file on a system having only busybox and nothing else.

```
hexdump -ve '"printf q" 16/1 "S%o" "q\n"' < INPUT_BINARY_PATH | tr Sq "\\\'" > OUTPUT.sh
```

```
sh OUTPUT.sh > OUTPUT_BINARY_PATH
```

The characters `S` and `q` are used to concisely work around symbol limitations in hexdump's format strings. `S` is translated into a backslash, to represent escaped octal bytes. `q` is translated into a single quote surrounding each line, so that `printf` interprets these escapes rather than the shell.

The use of `printf` could be replaced with `echo -ne`. The use of octal escaped bytes could be replaced with hexadecimal ones. The use of hexdump could likely be replaced by other similar utilities. More data can be placed on a single script line by increasing the number `16`.

Answer (score 0):

### Try out [`makeself`](https://makeself.io/)

It's 100% open source ([GPL v2 license](https://github.com/megastep/makeself/blob/master/COPYING)).

1. https://makeself.io/
2. https://github.com/megastep/makeself

---

How I found out about it:

If you download the latest version of Microchip's MPLAB X IDE For microcontrollers, here, for Linux: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-x-ide#tabs

```bash
wget https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/DEV/ProductDocuments/SoftwareTools/MPLABX-v6.10-linux-installer.tar
```

...and extract it and view it with `less`:

```bash
tar -xf MPLABX-v6.10-linux-installer.tar
less MPLABX-v6.10-linux-installer.sh
```

...you'll see it is a massive **1 GB!** shell script which contains this at the top:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# This script was generated using Makeself 2.1.5

CRCsum="108692005"
MD5="bbc1b2d1d3ab9ead5ad3ac936eda9b80"
TMPROOT=${TMPDIR:=/tmp}

label="MPLAB X 'v6.10' installer"
script="./MPLABX-v6.10-linux-installer.run"
scriptargs=""
targetdir="makeself-18675-20230516193821"
filesizes="999203313"
keep=n

#################################################################################
#### Added by Microchip to make these checks run first during installation ######
#################################################################################

check64BitLibraries()
{
...
```

Notice:

> This script was generated using Makeself 2.1.5

So, I recommend trying that out.

See also:

1. This may also be useful (not sure yet): https://www.xmodulo.com/embed-binary-file-bash-script.html
2. [Google search for "how to store a binary into an sh file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+store+a+binary+into+an+sh+file&oq=how+to+store+a+binary+into+an+sh+file&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.216j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score -2):

Sure it is!

You can for example dump any binary into a file with:

```
echo $binary > file
```

There are many installation scripts which do things like that.

Comment: `printf '%s' "$binary" > file` is safer, as `echo` will append an extra newline. How to disable that, as well as treatment of backslash-escaped characters in `$binary`, may differ between implementations of `echo`.

Comment: This will fail if `$binary` contains NUL (ASCII 0), HT (ASCII 9), or LF (ASCII 10), or sequences of multiple consecutive SP (ASCII 20), or if it contains `?` or `*` and the `nullglob` option is set. A lot of these can be addressed by writing `"$binary"` instead of `$binary`, but even then it will fail if `$binary` contains NUL. That's a dealbreaker for many (most?) binary files.

Comment: @chepner: The question specifies Bash.

Comment: @ruakh: `bash` would require `echo -n` at the least, but one also needs to check if `xpg_echo` is set, which affects how the escape characters are processed. It's simplest to just use `printf`. None of which helps with null characters, though.