# Windows batch script containing binary executable

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, base64, encode

I want to create a windows `batch` script, which will have a `base64` encoded program included. By included I mean - the encoded program will be "hardcoded" - there should be a "function" (or a code block) which will write the file line by line.

(like in this question related to Linux `Bash`: [Bash script containing binary executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410785/bash-script-containing-binary-executable))

I want to ask you what is the best method to do something like this, when it should apply to the following points:

- I want to use only the tools bundled with Windows (no additional libraries, executables etc)
- The file should be single - It can simply include the `base64` encoded string in any way
- I want t get the highet spossible performance

I've tried to convert each `base64` encoded line to an echo call, but this is very slow. Echoing 6000 lines takes about 10 seconds (I want to generate a file whcih will have about 10 000 lines with this method).

Is there a better method to do this? Maybe there is a "file splitter" in windows, which will allow me to split this batch script and "extract" somehow some lines (like extract lines 100-10100) and save them to another file?

A part of currently used file generation is as follows:

```
:getbin_Windows_x86
[...]
echo f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIAPgABAAAAsCVAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEiGBQAAAAAAAAAAAEAAOAAK>>%INSTALLER_BASE_TMP%
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA>>%INSTALLER_BASE_TMP%
echo AAAMAAAAAAAAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA>>%INSTALLER_BASE_TMP%
[...]
GOTO:EOF
```

I would love to do it using batch files, but if `Power Shell` will give me some better result, I'll move over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a binary file into Base64 is easy enough, as .Net contains the handy Convert class. Like so,

```
# Set up paths
$binSrcPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
$b64DstPath = "C:\temp\notepad++.exe.b64"

# Read the source binary as byte array
$binData = Get-Content -Path $binSrcPath -Encoding Byte

# Convert the bytes into a base64 encoded form
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binData)

# Save the encoded data
set-content $b64DstPath $base64
```

Now that the encoded binary is saved, let's convert it again to binary. Like so,

```
# Paths first
$b64DstPath = "C:\temp\notepad++.exe.b64"
$binDstPath = "C:\temp\notepad++.exe"

# Read the encoded data
$dataToBase64 = get-content $b64DstPath

# Decode the base64 encoding
$decodedData =  [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)

# Save the decoded data as a byte, not text
set-content -Path $binDstPath -Value $decodedData -Encoding Byte
```

Comparing the files with cmd's fc.exe shows not a thing has changed:

```
C:\>fc /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\temp\notepad++.exe"
Comparing files C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\NOTEPAD++\notepad++.exe and C:\TEMP\NOTEPAD++.EXE
FC: no differences encountered
```

In order to embed a base64 string in your Powershell script, I'd advise you to save the data in different a file. This is as base64 data will take quite some space and makes the script file itself a bit unwieldy. Embedding is rather straight-forward, like so:

```
# Declare a function that contains a bases64 string
function getB64Data {
    return "TVqAA..."
}

$binDstPath = "C:\temp\notepad++.exe"
# Read the base64 string into a variable
$dataToBase64 = getB64Data

# Decode the base64 encoding
$decodedData =  [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)

# Save the decoded data as a byte, not text
set-content -Path $binDstPath -Value $decodedData -Encoding Byte
```

Comment: +1 for the firt part, for the usage of the base 64 string I would have assign a var into a .PS1 file and . source this file.

Comment: Ok thank you, but how would you do that without using powershell (to support Windows xp default installation also) using only one file? Converting to base64 is also straghtforward using `certutil`. The problem occurs while embeding this encoded data. It REALLY has to be in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new batch file tool here that uses Jscript scripting built into Windows for speed (compared to a batch file), and written by Aacini: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4842

This tool creates a single batch file with the binary/multiple files inside and provides the user a way to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

If JScript is not an option, a "for" loop in a batch file can do the trick:

```
for /f "delims=] tokens=1" %%s in ('find /i /n "BASE64ENCODED" %~dpnx0') do set skip=%%s
for /f "skip=%skip:~1% tokens=*" %%l in (%~dpnx0) do echo %%l>>targetfile.exe
Goto :EOF

BASE64ENCODED
'put your encoded stuff here...
```

Unfortunately, this will not solve your performance issue... And to dynamically get the number of lines to skip, it reads the whole file twice.