# How to create a command-line executable in Clojure

Tags: java, ruby, clojure

I have written a program in Clojure and I'd like to execute it on the command-line *without* specifically invoking java on the command-line (such as `java -jar`).  I want a single executable file, such as `myprogram`, that accepts any arguments and runs my program.  Here are a couple things that might make this easier:

1. It's OK to assume Java is installed and that `java` is in the path.
2. Although a solution that works on Windows would be a great plus, you can assume that this is all being done on a UNIX-like operating system such as Mac OS X or Ubuntu.
3. It's OK to invoke Java in a script of some kind.
4. It's OK to use some other language, such as Ruby, Python or Perl, which the user may or may not have installed.  All-bash would be cool because I can assume people have that.
5. It's OK if I have to use some kind of tool to build a binary that will execute, but I am not looking for a .app or .exe file that expects to operate with a GUI interface (so for example, Oracle's appbundler is not what I'm looking for here).

I have gotten pretty far down this path with one approach, but I have to wonder if there's a better way.

**FOR REFERENCE ONLY: What I've Tried Already**

I'll describe my approach below, but any answers don't need to follow this approach at all.

What I have done is create a lein plugin called `makescript` that generates an uberjar, base64 encodes it, and places it inside a Ruby script in a so-called heredoc variable, like this:

```
# ...ruby script...
BASE64_JAR = <<-JAR_BOUNDARY
# [...base64 encoded file here...]
JAR_BOUNDARY
```

You should then be able to run the ruby script.  It will take the BASE64_JAR variable, unencode it, place it in a temporary file, and execute it by invoking `java -jar <filename>`.

The problem I'm having with this approach is that Ruby's `base64` library and Clojure's `clojure.data.codec.base64` libraries seem to be producing different strings to represent the jar, and a string encoded by Clojure does not decode to the original file if I use Ruby.  This may have something to do with the encoding of the strings themselves (UTF-8-related? maybe) between the two languages.  Here are repl/irb sessions that illustrate the disconnect:

```
repl=> (def jar-contents (slurp "../target/myproj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-002-standalone.jar"))
repl=> (count jar-contents) ;; => 9433328
repl=> (def a-str (String. (clojure.data.codec.base64/encode (.getBytes jar-contents)) "UTF-8"))
repl=> (count a-str)        ;; => 23265576

irb> f = File.open("target/pwgen-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-002-standalone.jar", "r").read()
irb> p f.length   # => 9657639
irb> b = Base64.encode64(f)
irb> p b.length   # => 13564973
```

Note the raw sizes are close but not the same, but the encoded versions are much different.

Although this is puzzling and I'd like to know why this happens, I think I can bypass the problem by having makescript just generate the uberjar and pass the path to another Ruby script, which then will base64 encode (and later decode, also using Ruby) the standalone JAR.  The question still stands: is there a better, simpler way?  Am I missing something obvious, or is this really as hard as it seems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do it, you can [uuencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) the jar file (or any other binary file) in a bash executable, see this for an example: [Embed a Executable Binary in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491704/embed-a-executable-binary-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just trying to bootstrap your app from a script using cleaner syntax. This might be most easily done like so:

create a new bash script called `myprogram`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# pass whatever command line args you have down through the script
java -jar myjar.jar
```

give it execute permissions

```
chmod +x myprogram
```

run it

```
./myprogram (with whatever params)
```

If you want to get rid of the `./` you'll need to move things around so the script gets picked up by your `PATH`.

Keep in mind that you're ***not creating a platform specific binary executable***. Doing so would pretty much defeat the purpose of using the jvm in the first place. You'd just be invoking it through an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: The problem with this is it requires me to have a separate jar file somewhere.  I suppose that is possible, but it's a little bit unpleasant.  As for the platform-specific binary, I think most big apps that use the JVM do exactly that -- thinking of Eclipse or jEdit for example.  In the end, though, all I want is self-contained command-line script.

Comment: @door_number_three You're right -- with this approach, you'd need to be able to reference the jar on the host system. Maybe you could write an install script as well that puts the jar where you need it, and then link to that from your script.

Answer (score 2):

What about running clojure as an interpretive script.  Create a new file called `mytest`:

```
#!/usr/bin/clojure
(print "hello world")
```

and then

```
chmod +x mytest
```

and then simply run it

```
./mytest
```

There are plenty of drawbacks to this.  It's really slow to start.  This simple 1 liner took over 2 seconds to run!  You're only going to get a single file.  Probably this is useful only for the most simple things.  But this could be useful if you're just trying to do something quickly which isn't production or test something.

Answer (score 2):

Now that [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/why-graal/) has matured a little bit, you may want to consider compiling your application to a binary executable.

There's a good tutorial of how to accomplish that [here](https://www.astrecipes.net/blog/2018/07/20/cmd-line-apps-with-clojure-and-graalvm/).