# insert binary code as here-doc into shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

src:unix programming environment

a shell script ./bundle :it works well with text file but binary code :(

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '# To unbundle , sh this file'
for i
do
    echo "echo $i 1>&2"
    echo "cat >$i <<'End of $i'"
    cat $i
    echo "End of $i"
done
```

a simple binary file named a.out,

```
% ./bundle a.out >> out
% chmod u+x out
% ./out # error happened
```

I got:

```
./out: line 8: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `End of a.out')
```

yeah, I know the `End of a.out' should be in a seprate line. But I don't know how to implemetate it.

who have some idea?

thx in advance. :D

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491704/embed-a-executable-binary-in-a-shell-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410785/bash-script-containing-binary-executable?lq=1

Comment: You could use base64 encode/decode, which is pretty standard these days...

Comment: @anishsane yeah, a cool method to do it! thx! base64 works very well.
just use base64 instead of cat in shell script. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can uuencode binary files (as [shar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) does), or do as [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) does, appending the binary as is and reading it out with `dd`.
(You could obviously also use either of these tools)

Comment: thank you! uuencode works well. and I will try other method later.