# Creare binary with no external dependencie

Tags: bash, external-dependencies

Hi, I'm creating a small bash script. I would like to make this script portable to any Linux system without having to install any additional packages to make it work.
The problem is that this script uses the wmctrl tool, which isn't present on many distributions, so the question is:
I can arrange the distribution of a version of wmctrl which can be run on any distribution without having to install anything. Create a version of wmctrl that has no external dependencies.
it's possible? and if so, how? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed a Executable Binary in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491704/embed-a-executable-binary-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Masso  I don't understand your question: So, you have a bash-program, which uses `wmctrl`, but since this is not portable, you are searching for a replacement for `wmctrl` which can run everywhere bash runs?

Comment: @user1934428 What I mean is: let's say I want to run my script on a computer that does not have wmctrl installed, the solution I would like to do is to distribute the wmctrl binary file together with my script in order to be able to call it from the script.
The problem is that the wmctrl binary file depends on other system libraries (glib2, libc6, libxmu, libxmu6, ...), which may not be installed on the computer, so what I was asking is: is it possible to get a wmctrl binary that can distribuoted with my script and that run without the need for any external library?

Comment: @Masso : IMO, this is not clear from your question. Hence, the problem is not related to _bash_, but to the fact on how to distribute wmctrl to systems which doesn't have them installed. Once you have solved this, you will also know how to adapt this to your script. I suggest that you ask a new question with this topic.